# Exception on LINQ query against LINQ2SQL/WCF class that inherits from an abstract class

Tags: c#, wcf, linq, asp.net-3.5

I'm having some problems running a LINQ query off of a LINQ2SQL class that inherits from a base abstract class.

```
[DataContract]
public abstract class AbstractClass
{
    [DataMember]
    public abstract int Foo { get; set; }
}


// LINQ2SQL class.
[DataContract]
public class ConcreteClass : AbstractClass
{
    [DataMember]
    public override int Foo { ... }
}
```

The problem occurs when I try to run a LINQ query against my Concrete Class. I get a SystemException saying, "Class member AbstractClass.Foo is unmapped." The query would look something like the following:

```
// Sample LINQ query.
result = from c in dataContext.ConcreteClasses where c.Foo == 42 select c;
```

Notice how the query is against CocnreteClass, but the error is on the AbstractClass. Any ideas whats going on here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the compiler was having problems infering the correct type. Instead of using the class returned by the LINQ2SQL context, it was using the base class, so I had to cast it to the correct type explicitly.

This previous example does NOT work:

```
result = from c in dataContext.ConcreteClasses where c.Foo == 42 select c;
```

This example does work:

```
result = from c in dataContext.ConcreteClasses where ((ConcreteClass)c).Foo == 42 select c;
```

Odd, but it works. Upvotes to anyone who can figure out why it would do that.

(Reference: [Very strange inheritance behavior.](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/linqprojectgeneral/thread/016ad28b-f813-4f26-9e70-2265a1943bad/))

Answer (score 0):

Does your abstract class have a constructor in it? I think I have had something similar to this before, and adding a protected constructor to the abstract class seemed to have fixed it.

Comment: Hrm, I believe the compiler auto-generates a parameterless constructor. In any case, I tried adding a non-abstract protected constructor as per your suggestion and it didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

Are your abstract and concrete classes LINQ2SQL classes using Table-Per-Type inheritance or some other data-centric inheritance?  I know that when you pass EF classes over WCF they lose inheritance information for some reason.

Comment: The query actually happens on the server side, so I wouldn't think it would lose any information.